# using express-hbs to precompile static pages

Tags: node.js, express, gulp, handlebars.js

I'm trying to use express-hbs to precompile some static HTML (with layouts and partials) in a gulp task as part of a "release this library" task. I have something that looks like

```
gulp.task 'compile', ->
  gulp.src './www/views/*.html'
    .pipe through.obj (file, enc, cb) ->
      //the missing part
    .pipe gulp.dest './temp'
```

I know I can just call hbs compile to compile the single file but that doesn't include any partials or layouts.

```
template = hbs.compile(file.contents.toString());
file.contents = new Buffer(template(data));
this.push(file);
cb();
```

I know I'm just missing something simple here looking at the source of express-hbs I should be able get a copy of the "render" function by calling the `hbs.express4` function and passing in all my options but I'm not sure what all I need to pass to that render function to get it to do the right thing.

I want to use the express.hbs plug in because we are using some of the helpers it adds to handlebars like `contentFor` etc.

UPDATE, The Solution:

```
gulp.task 'compile', ->
  gulp.src './www/views/*.html'
    .pipe through.obj (file, enc, cb) ->
      render = hbs.create().express3
        viewsDir: __base + 'views'
        partialsDir: __base + 'views/partials'
        layoutDir: __base + 'views/layouts'
        defaultLayout: __base + 'views/layouts/layout.html'
        extName: 'html'

      locals = {
        settings: {
          views: __base + 'views'
        }
      }

      self = this;
      render file.path, locals, (err, html) ->
        if(!err)
          file.contents = new Buffer(html);
          self.push(file);
          cb();
        else
          console.log "failed to render #{file.path}"
    .pipe gulp.dest './temp'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a test in the express-hbs repo called nonExpress that looks like it does something similar to what you want.

https://github.com/barc/express-hbs/blob/master/test/nonExpress.js